# Detect the last edited element on 'outside' click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Strange title, but not so ordinary situation/problem, too...

I have editable fields in html table row:

```
 <?php foreach($userlist as $key=>$val): ?>
  <tr class="content" id="example" data-id="<?php echo $val->id; ?>">
    <td valign="top" class="editable" data-delid="<?php echo $val->id; ?>" data-name="id" ><?php echo $val->id; ?></td>
    <td valign="top" class="editable" data-name="username"><?php echo $val->username; ?></td>
    <td valign="top" class="editable" data-name="firstname"><?php echo $val->firstname; ?></td>
    <td valign="top" class="editable" data-name="lastname"><?php echo $val->lastname; ?></td>
    <td valign="top" class="editable" data-name="email"><?php echo $val->email; ?></td>
    <td valign="top" class="editable" data-name="phone"><?php echo $val->phone; ?></td>
    <td valign="top" class="editable" data-name="activated"><?php echo $val->activated; ?></td>
    <td valign="top" class="editable" data-name="role"><?php echo $val->role; ?></td>
    <!--<td><input class="see_more" type="button" value="Reveal More" /></td>-->
  </tr>
  <tr class="test_table">

  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Rows are created dynamically, and showed via AJAX (this code is part of codeigniter view file).

Request:
Fields should be editable on double click, BUT updated values must be saved on OUTSIDE CLICK?!

**"I need it so that when you click away or outside of the input text
the data goes to the database".**

So, click can occur anywhere, except on editable field, i guess - single click on editable field shouldn't trigger ajax update.

I am working on code by someone else, and i modified it, so updating of values works fine on ENTER key press.

JQuery code:

```
$(".editable").dblclick(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var currentEle = $(this);
    var value = $(this).html();

    var input_name=$(this).data('name');


    updateVal(currentEle, value, input_name);
});



    function updateVal(currentEle, value, input_name) {

        $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');



        $(".thVal").focus();

        $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());

                id=$(currentEle).parent().data('id');
                $.post( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>update_ajax", { id: id, field: input_name, value: $(this).val() })
    .done(function( data ) {
    //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    //something to output, or rather not?
    });

            }
        });



    /* $(document).click (function () {
    var inputa=$(currentEle).data('name');  

    console.log(inputa);


            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
            id=$(currentEle).parent().data('id');





        $.post( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>update_ajax", { id: id, field: inputa, value:  $(currentEle).html() })
    .done(function( data ) {
    //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    //something to output, or rather not?
    });



        });*/




    $('.thVal').on('click',function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });     



    }
```

You will notice my poor try, commented out...it doesn't work - it updates more fields, with same values (so, i can't connect field name/id and its value, and send it to db)

Right now, i am really not sure that mentioned scenario is even possible, but, maybe some of gurus here will have some ideas. :) I can provide more details, if needed....

Comment: Have you tried the JQuery "blur" event? It triggers when an element loses focus (http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Comment: I have checked it, but i'm not sure how to use it, in this case... Click (somewhere) on document body should start ajax update... P.S. i have tried to check if row hasClass selected, but... click on table row toogles selected class (already in code, i guess that functionality should be kept) - so, second click - no data for further manipulation... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an AJAX request to save some data when you click away from a text field, the JQuery blur event does it (it triggers when the element loses focus). In your case, it would be something like:

```
$('.editable').blur(function() {
  $.ajax('/backend_function_to_save_data', {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      value: $(this).val()
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Handle error
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      // Success message?
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, seems reasonable, but now i have strange issue -> element doesn't loose focus (omg)... I will re-check code.... this seems like only possible solution.

Comment: Thank you! I will probably shoot my self now. :D